Maximum size of a chain of sets, each of cardinality less than $\kappa$
Suppose we have a collection $\mathcal C$ of sets forming a chain (i.e., the collection of sets is totally ordered by inclusion).  We can probably assume all the sets are subsets of some ambient set $X$.  Assume ZFC.
(1) For finite sets:
It is well-known that $|\mathcal C|\le\aleph_0$ (since for each $n\in\omega$ there can be at most one $A\in\mathcal C$ of size $n$).  And furthermore, $|\bigcup\mathcal C|\le\aleph_0$.
These bounds are attained for example by choosing the chain $\mathcal C$ to be the set of all ordinals $\alpha<\omega$, which is a chain of finite sets.
(2) For countable sets:
If all sets in the chain are countable (= have cardinality $<\aleph_1$), there are bounds on the sizes of the chain and of its union: $|\mathcal C|\le\aleph_1$ and $|\bigcup\mathcal C|\le\aleph_1$.  And the chain $\mathcal C$ consisting of all ordinals $\alpha<\omega_1$ shows the bounds are attained.
There seems to be a proof of this at Why should the union of such a family of sets have cardinality $\aleph_1?$.
(Added: As indicated in the comments, the assertion for $|\mathcal C|$ is false)
(3) General case: Suppose $\kappa$ is some infinite cardinal.
The chain $\mathcal C$ consisting of all ordinals $\alpha<\kappa$ has cardinality $\kappa$ and its union has cardinality $\kappa$.
In general, the following should be true:

For any chain $\mathcal C$ of sets of cardinality $<\kappa$, there are bounds $|\mathcal C|\le\kappa$ and $|\bigcup\mathcal C|\le\kappa$.

Can someone provide a proof?  (For the proof linked at case (2), I understand the reduction to the well-ordered case, but the well-ordered case itself is not quite clear, I think.)
(Added: As indicated in the comments, the assertion for $|\mathcal C|$ is false)

Your claim in the countable case is already false. While $|\cup \mathcal{C}| \leq \aleph_1$ is true, $|\mathcal{C}| \leq \aleph_1$ is false unless you assume the continuum hypothesis. Indeed, the collection of sets of rationals smaller than a given real number is a chain of countable sets of cardinality continuum.

For the general question, $|\cup \mathcal{C}| \leq \kappa$ is true. For the bound on the cardinality of the chain itself, as indicated in my comments about the countable case, your claim is certainly false. You do get $|\mathcal{C}| \leq \kappa^{<\kappa}$, but I’m not sure if you can get anything better.

@DavidGao This is great.  When you get the chance, would you mind putting this in an answer, with an explanation of $|\mathcal{C}| \leq \kappa^{<\kappa}$?

Let's write $\DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{ch}\ch({<}\kappa) = \sup\{|\mathcal{C}|\mid \mathcal{C}\text{ is a chain of sets, each of cardinality}<\kappa\}$.
Let $(L,\leq)$ be a linear order. By a cut in $L$, I just mean a downwards-closed set, i.e., $C\subseteq L$ such that for all $x\leq y$, if $y\in C$ then $x\in C$. Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\Cut}{Cut}\Cut(L) = \{C\subseteq L\mid C\text{ is a cut}\}$, and note that $(\Cut(L),\subseteq)$ is a chain of sets.
Now suppose $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq)$ is a chain of sets. For $x,y\in \bigcup\mathcal{C}$, define $x\trianglelefteq y$ iff for all $C\in \mathcal{C}$, if $y\in C$ then $x\in C$. This relation $\trianglelefteq$ is a linear preorder. If we quotient by the induced equivalence relation (i.e., identifying elements of $\bigcup \mathcal{C}$ if they are elements of exactly the same sets in $\mathcal{C}$), we obtain a linear order $(\DeclareMathOperator{\Lin}{Lin}\Lin(\mathcal{C}),\leq)$. The image of each $C\in \mathcal{C}$ under the quotient map is a cut in $\Lin(\mathcal{C})$, so the chain $(\mathcal{C},\leq)$ embeds into $\Cut(\Lin(\mathcal{C}))$.
These observations should make it clear that $\ch({<}\kappa)$ is closely related to the number of cuts in linear orders.

For a cardinal $\kappa$, $\DeclareMathOperator{\ded}{ded}\ded(\kappa)$ is the supremum of $|\Cut(L)|$ over all linear orders $(L,\leq)$ of cardinality $\kappa$.
Here are some facts about $\ded(\kappa)$:

For all $\kappa$, $\kappa<\ded(\kappa)\leq 2^\kappa$. (So if GCH holds, then $\ded(\kappa) = 2^\kappa = \kappa^+$ for all $\kappa$.)
$\ded(\aleph_0) = 2^{\aleph_0}$.
For any cardinal $\kappa$ of uncountable cofinality, it is consistent that $\ded(\kappa)<2^\kappa$.

For more on $\ded(\kappa)$, see the introduction of On the number of Dedekind cuts and two-cardinal models of dependent theories by Chernikov and Shelah.
Similarly, we can write $\ded({<}\kappa) = \sup_{\lambda<\kappa}\ded(\lambda)$, the supremum of $|\Cut(L)|$ over all linear orders $(L,\leq)$ of cardinality $<\kappa$.
Since $\lambda<\ded(\lambda)\leq 2^\lambda$ for all $\lambda<\kappa$, we have $\kappa\leq \ded({<}\kappa)\leq 2^{<\kappa}$.

I claim that for all infinite $\kappa$, $\ch({<}\kappa) = \ded({<}\kappa)$.
In one direction, if $L$ is a linear order with $|L|<\kappa$, then $(\Cut(L),\subseteq)$ is a chain of sets, each of cardinality $\leq |L|<\kappa$, so $\ded({<}\kappa)\leq \ch({<}\kappa)$.
The other direction is not so immediate, because even if each set in $\mathcal{C}$ has cardinality $<\kappa$, we might have $|\Lin(\mathcal{C})| = |\bigcup\mathcal{C}| = \kappa$.
Nevertheless, let $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq)$ is a chain of sets, each of cardinality $<\kappa$. Let $f\colon \alpha\to \mathcal{C}$ be an order-preserving injective map, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $\mathrm{im}(f)$ is cofinal in $\mathcal{C}$ (this can be constructed by transfinite recursion).
Note that $\alpha\leq \kappa$. Indeed, if $\alpha>\kappa$, then for each $\beta<\kappa$, we can pick some $x_\beta\in f(\beta+1)\setminus f(\beta)$. The $(x_\beta)_{\beta\in \kappa}$ are distinct, and they are all elements of $f(\kappa)$, so $|f(\kappa)|\geq \kappa$, contradiction.
Now for all $\beta<\alpha$, let $\mathcal{C}_\beta = \{C\in \mathcal{C}\mid C\subseteq f(\beta)\}$, an initial segment of the chain $\mathcal{C}$. Note that $\bigcup\mathcal{C}_\beta = f(\beta)$, so $|\bigcup \mathcal{C}_\beta| <\kappa$. Thus, since $\mathcal{C}_\beta$ embeds in $\Cut(\Lin(C_\beta))$ and $|\Lin(C_\beta)|\leq |\bigcup C_\beta|<\kappa$, we have $|\mathcal{C}_\beta|\leq \ded({<}\kappa)$. Now piecing the whole chain back together, we have
\begin{align*}
|\mathcal{C}| &= |\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} C_\beta|\\
&\leq |\alpha|\cdot \sup_{\beta<\alpha}|C_\beta|\\
&\leq \kappa\cdot \ded({<}\kappa)\\
&\leq \ded({<}\kappa),
\end{align*}
since, as observed above, $\kappa\leq \ded({<}\kappa)$. This establishes $\ch({<}\kappa)\leq \ded({<}\kappa)$.

Comments:

If GCH holds, $2^{{<}\kappa} = \kappa$ for all infinite $\kappa$, so $\ch({<}\kappa) = \kappa$.
$\ch({<}\aleph_0) = \aleph_0$ and $\ch({<}\aleph_1) = 2^{\aleph_0}$.
The upper bound of $2^{{<}\kappa}$ is a slight improvement to the upper bound $\kappa^{{<}\kappa}$ claimed by David Gao in the comments. These can differ when $\kappa$ is singular.
It's not clear to me whether the supremum in the definition of $\ch({<}\kappa)$ is always attained, i.e., whether there is always a chain of sets, each of cardinality $<\kappa$, such that the chain has cardinality $\ch({<}\kappa)$.


Beautiful answer! It will take me a little while to look at all this in detail.
